# How to Avoid Duplicate subfolder creation while writing to partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to Overwrite a single partition using below code but instead of Overwriting/replacing existing partition, It's creating subfolder in it.

Please advise how can i get it to work. Below code creates folder as `/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/my_date=2018-01-03/`

But i want it to replace existing folder `/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/my_date=2018-01-03/`

I am trying to Overwrite a single partition using below code but instead of Overwriting/replacing existing partition, It's creating subfolder in it.

Please advise how can i get it to work. Below code creates folder as

```
/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/my_date=2018-01-03/

df.write.mode("Overwrite").partitionBy("my_date").parquet("/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/")
```

Above code creates folder as `/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/my_date=2018-01-03/`

I want this on Spark 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Actually the above code create/replace any folder(partition) under the below path

```
/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/
```

So, if you change the data it will insert new subfolder

```
/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/my_date=2018-01-02
/data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/my_date=2018-01-03
```

if you need to replace the new partition this is a common problem it can be solved using the below line

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("/root/path/to/data/partition_col=value")
```

you can then write some code to get the distinct partition from your code and then use `df.foreachPartition{partition=> some code }` and pass the partition to the save command

Update: We can select distinct partition and filter dataframe and write each one alone

```
 val uniquePartitionNames = df.select($"colname").distinct().collect() 
  for (partition <- uniquePartitionNames ) {
    val filteredDFBaseOnPartition = df.where($"colname" === partition)
    filteredDFBaseOnPartition .write.mode("Overwrite").save("path/colname="+partition)
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to clear older data like  /my_date=2018-01-01/ or /my_date=2018-01-02/ . Your solution will erase older data. I just want to replace that single partition

Comment: You can you foreach partition. Please check my updated answer again

Comment: @user8373873 another solution I update my post can be select distinct partition and write everyone with specific name

Comment: I tried SAVE command but it gave me result as /data/input/STATS/my_date=2018-01-03/my_date=2018-01-03/